# Powershell - filter by Date and Name

Tags: powershell

In a file I would like to Delete files that contain "**Warranty**" only AND **after 30 days the file must be deleted**.

In the end it would be necessary that the recent "Warranty", which is less than 30 days old.

Here is a script that does not work...but the principle is :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\..\Trial" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -and -filterscript $_.Name -match "Warranty"} | Remove-Item
```

Can you help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `Filter` parameter and `File` switch to first get files with "Warranty" in their name.

Also, as commented earlier, you are probably looking for the `LastWriteTime` property, not the `CreationTime`.

Try this:

```
# midnight 30 days ago
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\..\Trial" -Filter '*Warranty*' -File -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate} | 
Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't have the parameter `-filterscript` after the `-and` The following code worked for me :)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\..\Trial" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get- 
Date).AddDays(-30) -and $_.Name -match "Warranty"} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not working on my end... I'll try to understand why then... :)

Comment: for me it is working. Can you tell me the absolute path to the folder? Is it C:\Trial ?

Comment: I think it doesn't work because: 
If I follow your script: it takes the creation date and the creation date is 02/25/2020 but the modification date is 08/01/2020... 
I'll have to wait a few days to test the script...

Comment: Yes you probably would have to change that, I just took that part from your example

Comment: @Smarty13 If you copy a file to a new location, the copy will get the CreationTime time stamp of the time the copy was made. Change `$_.CreationTime` into `$_.LastWriteTime` to get the last modified date.

Comment: Yes, when I was looking I saw this order too. Thank you Theo for your information.